# Parentheses surrounding footnote body

Tags: word-usage, writing-style, parentheses, footnotes

It's unbelievably hard to find relevant information online, as almost every Google search just gives pages of advice and questions regarding citations and referencing styles.

If I use a footnote in place of information I would normally enclose with parentheses, should my footnote body text be enclosed with parentheses? *e.g.*,

> The (entirely subject-to-change) plan is to ...

If I wanted to move that piece of parenthesis into a footnote for whatever purpose, is the following footnote correct?

> 1. (entirely subject-to-change)

If I shouldn't be using the parentheses, then what should that footnote look like?

Comment: I would say the parantheses and footnote are serving the same purpose in this usage — to provide additional, secondary information. As such, I wouldn't see the need to use parantheses in the footnote

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about writing (presentation) style, not about English language and usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use parentheses in the footnote, as the footnote itself is functionally analogous to the parentheses you were first trying to eliminate. Simply:

> 1. Entirely subject to change

There are no hyphens because, as George Stirling pointed out in his answer, the footnote is supplementary to the "plan" its referring to.

I also wouldn't write such a short footnote with so little information in it. Maybe you could beef it up?

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I also wouldn't write such a short footnote - it was merely an example. The hyphenation wasn't really a concern either.

However, should the footnote as you have it end with a full stop?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you'll be placing your footnote marker after 'plan', it would be more correct to omit the hyphens in the footnote.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I've edited my post because of your observation.